# Just want to transfer all data from table in one GAE datastore to identical table in another datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

I haven't been able to find anything that specifically addresses this problem.

Google App Engine has a somewhat straightforward set of instructions for downloading/uploading data.  They specifically say this technique can be used to transfer data from one datastore to another.

I used their examples for download and upload.  On download, it worked, and generated what looked like a local Sql database file... it wasn't CSV or XML, it was binary.

So I go to upload it, and it says that I've exceeded my quota on put().

I've throttled the thing way down (see below), so I guess that can't be it.  My next step would be to try to use the loader configuration file, which I think would require importing the relevant model classes, etc.  I really don't want to go that complicated if I don't have to.  All I want to do is transfer data from a table in one datastore to the identical table in another datastore.  I dread that the reason may be the binary data file, but if the downloader generates that by default, why can't it restore the table from it by default?  Anyway... Has anyone run into this, and how did you resolve it?  Here's my command line:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Owner>appcfg.py upload_data --kind=ZipCodeData --filen
ame="c:\WG_DOWNLOADS\zipcodedata.txt" --url=http://stage-omni-rocket.appspot.com
/_ah/remote_api --rps_limit=1 --batch_size=1 --bandwidth_limit=25000 --http_limi
t=1 --num_threads=1
```

Here's my error:

OverQuotaError: The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is avai
lable.

Comment: If it says you exceeded your quota, that's because you exceeded your quota. Enable billing and try again.

Comment: Alternately, if you don't mind the wait, you can just leave it running until it finishes. I believe the bulkloader will gradually back off and retry until more quota becomes available. Or you can cancel it and resume later using the progress database.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you over used your free quota and in order for the upload to work you need to enable billing or wait till the free quota will reset (every 24 hours at 00:00 PST)